# Avoiding a big data redirect in MVC without using TempData

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Problem:

1. You have a custom controller action, which modifies a large amount of data (around 5MB).
2. You need to pass this data to another controller action, which you are NOT allowed to modify.

What's the best way to do this?

A normal RedirectToAction would result in a huge data post.

TempData can't be used as a workaround as you cannot modify the other controller to read the tempdata.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Import")]
    public ActionResult ImportPost(int id)
    {
    var bigData = GetBigData(id);
    bigData = ManipulateBigDataIntoFormatOtherControllerUnderstands(bigData);


    // TODO: redirect to other controller (which has HttpPost attribute), somehow??
}
```

Comment: are temp files or a database transaction options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, came up with an answer right after posting:

```
var c = new Namespace.Controllers.OtherController();
c.ControllerContext = ControllerContext;
return c.Action(bigData);
```